# Python - Why does this list comprehension return an empty list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tasks, and I'm trying to select all tasks with a given id.

```
# temp global tasks list
tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
        'done': False
    }
]

# here I try to select some tasks. 'request.args.get('id')' is 2 in my test
selectedTasks = tasks

if 'id' in request.args:
    selectedTasks = [task for task in selectedTasks if task['id'] == request.args.get('id')]
```

If I run this, `selectedTasks` is empty. However I don't see why.

I tried printing some values:

```
# just before the list comprehension
print(selectedTasks, file=sys.stderr)
print(request.args.get('id'), file=sys.stderr)
print(selectedTasks[1]['id'], file=sys.stderr)
```

This prints:

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'Buy groceries', 'description': 'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 'done': False}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'Learn Python', 'description': 'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 'done': False}]
2
2
```

So the tasks are all there, `request.args.get('id')` is correct, and the second task has id `2`. So why doesn't this work?

Comment: Does it has `2` or `'2'`? (a string?)

Comment: Provide some more code as to who is "request", it is important what type the id is.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh that could be it! request.args are url parameters. So I get id from this url: http://.../api/v1.0/tasks?id=2.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Just tried it, and this was indeed the problem. I now provide a type parameter in the get function: request.args.get('id', type=int). This tries to cast it to an int, and returns None if it can't. If you provide this as answer I'll accept ;) Such a stupid thing to miss :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `request.args`, the `id` is a string, and in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), `2` is *not* equal to `'2'`:

```
>>> 2 == '2'
False
```

So we can simply convert the string to an `int(..)`, and solve it like:

```
if 'id' in request.args:
    the_id = int(request.args.get('id'))
    selectedTasks = [task for task in selectedTasks if task['id'] == the_id]
```

Or, you can - like you say yourself - provide a `type` parameter to the `.get()` method to do the conversion at the `.get()` level:

```
if 'id' in request.args:
    the_id = request.args.get('id',type=int)
    selectedTasks = [task for task in selectedTasks if task['id'] == the_id]
```

Comment: I used `request.args.get('id', type=int)`, but basically does the same I think. I find it looks nicer. Is there a reason to use `int(...)` over `.get('id', type=int)`?

Comment: @TheOddler: not at all. I think it is indeed a more elegant way to do so. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what framework you're using to provide the request object, but it's highly likely that request.args does return a list of strings. You should try casting the request argument to an int.

```
if 'id' in request.args:
    task_id = request.args.get('id')
    assert task_id.isdigit()
    task_id = int(task_id)
    selectedTasks = [task for task in selectedTasks if task['id'] == task_id]
```